# Harp js + blog example: Is there a way to set default partial for articles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, harp

I'm playing around with the Harp static site generator and there is this blog example around everywhere, see for instance: http://kennethormandy.com/journal/start-a-blog-with-harp

I was asking if there is a way to set a default jade template/partial for all articles instead of defining one for each article which seems rather inconvenient to me?

E.g. outline of my app

```
/public
/articles
  _data.json        <--- json with my articles
  article.jade      <--- I would like to have one template for all articles
                           instead of having to add files:
                           article1.jade, 
                           article2.jade, ...
/index.jade
```

/articles/_data.json

```
{
 "article1": {
    "title": "Some article"
 },
 "article2": {
    "title": "Another one"
 }
 // eventually some more articles ...
}
```

/index.jade

```
...
ul
  each article, slug in public.articles._data
    li
      a(href="/articles/#{ slug }") #{ article.name }     // generated link only works when for each slug (e.g. "article1") a jade file exists
...
```

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a `_layout.jade` file in the `articles/` directory to get what you’re after: https://harpjs.com/docs/development/layout

Building on the multiple layouts example on that docs page:

```
public/
  _layout.jade
  index.jade
  about.md
  articles/
    _data.json
    _layout.jade
    article1.jade
    article2.md
```

Here, `index.jade` and `about.md` will use the `_layout.jade` file in the root of the project. Anything in the articles directory—in this case, `article1.jade` and `article2.md`—will use the `_layout.jade` in the same directory.

This is a feature built into Harp and works for both Jade and EJS. If you are using Jade for everything, you could also use Jade specific features like `block` and `extends`. There’s also an example of that on the same docs page.